# Recommended C++ Include Practice

Tags: c++, include

In the following scenario, what would be the best approach to include the `<string>` header?

main.cpp

```
#include "extra.h"

int main() {
    func("A string");
    return 0;
}
```

extra.h

```
#ifndef EXTRA_H
#define EXTRA_H

    #include <string>

    void func(std::string);

#endif
```

extra.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "extra.h"

void func(std::string str) {
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The code you have looks correct.  Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. I've gone through a few different tutorials and some of them recommend the inclusion of header files in .cpp files rather than relying on transitive inclusion, thus I was wondering if I should add the `#include <string>` line in extra.cpp and main.cpp as well.

Comment: What is "best" is pretty subjective. Personally, as a general rule I include what I use, but in this case that may be more of a style thing. If the same developers are in control of the `.h` and `.cpp` files and you know for a fact that `extra.h` includes `<string>`, then you might consider it optional to include it in the `.cpp`. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `extra.h` includes `<string>` because it uses it directly.  There is no direct use of `std::string` in your `main.cpp` so it would be strange to include `<string>` there.

Further, including `<string>` in `extra.cpp` is totally unnecessary because the use of `std::string` is in a function signature which you know is declared in `extra.h`, plus the maintenance of the two `extra` files can reasonably be expected to be done as a single operation, so there's no worry about `extra.h` suddenly not including `<string>` and then breaking `extra.cpp`, because they'd be maintained together.

Answer (score 1):

A header file should have as little includes as possible. This keeps it clean, and also allows for faster compilation. If the header file needs a complete type you have to include the include file for that type in your header file, else use forward declarations.

For example **main.h**

```
#pragma once

// if your header uses a full type (see function h)
// it needs to know the size of the type
// then include header file for that type in your header

#include <string>
void h(std::string str);

// if your header only has references or pointers to a type
// then add a forward declaration of that type.
// The compiler only has to know the size for the reference/pointer

struct struct_t; 

void f(const struct_t& s);
void g(const struct_t* s);
```

And then **main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>
// #include <string> not really needed already done in "main.h"

// full declaration of struct_t in the place where it is needed.
// note this could also be in done in its own header file. 
struct struct_t
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

void f(const struct_t& s)
{
    std::cout << s.value1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.value2 << std::endl;
}

void g(const struct_t* s)
{
    std::cout << s->value1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s->value2 << std::endl;
}

void h(std::string s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct_t values{ 0, 42 };
    f(values);
    g(&values);
    h("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Would wrapping the string in a structure (struct, class, etc) be more efficient than including the `<string>` header in extra.h?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, wrapping the string wasn't what I wanted to show, I updated the example.

Comment: If you're creating a set of header files for a client then yes, hiding complex types from a client is a valid approach, but then I usually use abstract base classes (interfaces) and the pimpl pattern : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl. But that was not your initial question :)